# Trigger method of the item within the ItemsControl using Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

I have an `ItemsControl` as follow:

```html
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Action ($dataContext).Launch]">
                    <Grid Background="LightSteelBlue" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="4"/>
                </ContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The `ItemsControl`'s items source has a binding to an `ObservableCollection<Item>` in the view model.

The following is the definition of `Item`

```
public class Item
{
    public void Launch()
    {
    }
}
```

When double-clicked on the `Item`, I'm trying to trigger the `Launch()` method of the `Item` by using the following syntax:

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Action ($dataContext).Launch]"
```

However I get the "No target found for method" error message.

Am I using the syntax correctly? Or the shorthand does not support such use case?

UPDATE:

My view model is as follows:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    // Binding Properties.
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public void Launch()
    {

    }

    // ctor.
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        Items.Add(new Item());
        Items.Add(new Item());
    }
}
```

When I tried to use the following syntax to trigger `Launch()` method of `Item`, it trigger the `Launch()` method of the view model instead.

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Action Launch]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I removed `Launch()` method from my view model, `Launch()` method for `Item` is triggered. It seems like if a matched method is found in the view model, the framework will execute that particular method in the view model. If none is found in the view model, the framework search within its current context and execute the method if matched method is found.